# I plan to send my child to mission school at 4+, should I send them somewhere else before then?

Tags: primary-schooler, school

My son is 22 months old.

My wife's dream is to enroll our only son to one of the finest schools in Bangalore like Bishop Cotton, Frank  Anthony, St. Joseph, Baldwin Boys et. al. My understanding is, all these schools start taking admission from LKG/Nursery, which means I have to wait until he is 4+.

The problem is, most schools in Bangalore apart from the Salesian schools in Bangalore start from pre-school which means I have to admit my Kid from 2.5+.

This means if I am able to secure an admission to one of the schools like NPS (National Public School), Presidency and similar schools where you have to pay a hefty donation among other fees which actually admit kids from 2.5+, it would be fruitless if I plan to shift my kid the next year.

On the other hand, if I wait until my son is 4+, it would be a risky proposition in case I am not able to secure admission to one of the a good catholic mission schools.

What is the right approach I should take in this situation if I plan to admit my son to a christian missionary school?

Comment: Welcome to Parenting.SE.  Unfortunately this question is probably too specific for this stack as it appears to be about admission to a specific school.  Few people are likely to know the answer.  It may help if you could show more of your research, for example: by giving more detail on the entry requirements for the missionary schools or by expanding on the options for putting your child into the paid schooling system at a later age.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about specific location

Comment: With over 4 million people in Bangalore, I don't agree that this is too localized.  This has the potential to be useful to a *lot* of parents.

Comment: More information on the (now deprecated) "too localized" justification for closing, including when *not* to close something as too localized: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/87415/166646

Comment: Abhijit, I've made an effort to make your question easier to understand, and changed the title to attract more attention from people who might have useful advice. If you feel I've removed critical information, you can roll back the changes, or ask me to do so, and I'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here for me is that I lack context regarding Bangalore, so my advice is going to be pretty generic.

Firstly, this is less critical than you might think. Between 2 and 4 is no more a critical time when your child needs to be at school than between 7 and 9. [In countries like Britain, 4 to 5 is the norm.](http://www.babycentre.co.uk/a1053324/is-my-child-ready-for-school) [In Scandinavian countries, 6 to 7](http://www.nfer.ac.uk/nfer/index.cfm?9B1C0068-C29E-AD4D-0AEC-8B4F43F54A28) is. If they miss out on some schooling from 2 till 4, they would still be able to catch up, and if you're supporting their learning at home by working on their reading and maths skills, they'll probably be fine in their class.

At the end of the day, you have a risk here, and you need to understand and control it. I don't understand Bangalore's education system well enough to comment on the consequences of missing NPS from 2.5 to 4 and then not getting into Mission School, but **you should**. Will they still get educated? What quality will that education be? **Make contact with parents who've sent their children to the Mission schools and to NPS, and talk to them about that. Do the research into what happens if your child waits and then doesn't get in.** This should be something that the mission school should be able to help you with.

It's also important to aim for what you want. When talking to the Mission School parents, make sure they leave the conversation thinking of you and your child as someone they'd like to be a part of their child's school. When talking to the Mission School, make sure that they know that they're your first choice, you just want to shield your child from any consequences of your decision.

Hope this helps, and good luck!